# Power BI subscription for report using SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: powerbi, subscription, ssas-tabular, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

How do we create subscription for report in Power BI that is using underlying tabular model? Power BI is giving error while creating subscription saying **"You cannot subscribe others because this artifact has row-level security or the dataset is using a Live Connection to Analysis Services"**

I could create subscription for myself as I am admin for the workspace. But I can not add other email IDs in the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI is used to restrict data access for given users.

One workaround could be to add your co-workers as members of the workspace. because in Power BI service, members of a workspace have access to datasets in the workspace. RLS doesn't restrict this data access.

For more info, you can see this: 
[RLS in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls)